# Sending back JSON object

Tags: json

I have a requirement where i need to validate the year for a vehicle and if vehicle is out of range in the request . i need to send the reference of correspondence vehicle which fails validation.
eg: In below case for vehicle 2 year is less than 2000 then i need to send some thing like cover.vehicle[1].year is out of range. How do i frame the fully address of JSON in DTO dynamically?

**Request:**

```
"cover": [
                {

                    "vehicle": {
                        "year": 2019
                        "make" : "toyota"
                    }, 
                    " vehicle": {
                        "year": 1980
                        "make" : "honda"
                    },
}
]
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "description": "Year is out of range,
 "field": "cover[1].vehicle.year",
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the language too so that you can get a more precise and specific answer?

Comment: Apologies it is Java

Answer (score 0):

I think vehicles should really have unique IDs here. Then you can uniquely identify vehicles based on the ID. Otherwise, what if you have a BUNCH of invalid vehicles, with the same year and make? Do you want to only return the first invalid one?

If you really don't want to do this, then I suggest returning the entire invalid vehicle like : :

```
{
    "description" : "Year is out of range"
    "year": 2019
    "make" : "toyota"
}
```

Then you might get to come up with some complex nesting of error mechanism for multiple errors....

I suggest IDs and then returning an error object that refers to an array of invalid vehicleIDs, and set the HTTP status to 400.

Comment: Thanks Brian. What if there are multiple levels of nesting. E.g.: inside cover array,make is also an array of values .do you recommend having IDs at each array level to uniquely identify.

Comment: Yes, I recommend IDs at every level of nesting - every time you want to be able to uniquely identify something, and ID is helpful. Even when we're not sure, right now, how we want to uniquely identify something, we include IDs since we'll probably need to uniquely identify it later.